# Does MXNET has auto-differentiation feature?

Tags: tensorflow, mxnet

Mxnet and Tensorflow both declare that they has auto-differentiation feature.

In Mxnet, I need to define the backward part when creating a new op(like loss function), but not in Tensorflow.

In my knowledge, auto-differentiation means I don't need to care about the backward part. So, does mxnet has auto-differentiation feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MXNet has autograd.

Here is a tutorial: http://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter01_crashcourse/autograd.html

Comment: umm...The pull request is closed several days ago, hope it to be merged in the future. Thank you.

Comment: The examples got merged into the 'nn' branch: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/tree/nn/example/autograd. Will be merged into master soon.

Comment: Thanks. That is great!

Comment: Autograd is now available in master. Check this tutorial to get started: http://mxnet.io/tutorials/gluon/2-autograd.html